# Legacy HTML - Text link form submission with text value

Tags: javascript, html, servlets, legacy

I am working on an old school project in which I have to add dynamic form submission to a JSP page. The link will be generated dynamically, so I need to track what link has been clicked. e.g.,

```
<form id="download" method="GET" action="/DownloadReports.jsp">
    <table>
        <tr>
           <td><a href="#">Report Name to download</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

What I need to do is to submit this form so that in my servlet, I know which link has been clicked. I realized that I have to call javascript like this:

```
  function submit() {     
      form = document.getElementById('download');
      form.submit();          
  }
```

Then I will add `<a href="#" onclick="submit(); return false;">` ... But now my questions is, how would I send my clicked link value to the servlet?

Comment: Use AJAX, GET, POST?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a hidden input in form and set it in javascript which will be sent to the server.

**HTML**

```
<form id="download" method="GET" action="/DownloadReports.jsp">
<input type=hidden name="formName" >
    <table>
        <tr>
           <td><a href="#">Report Name to download</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

In Javascript,set the hidden input as per your requirement.I am not sure how you are dynamically generating html.

Then you can retrieve this input in servlet like this

```
String form = request.getParameter("formName");
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, I have figured it out. I will be making the form submit via javascript, as i mentioned and I will have 1 hidden field and that will be "requestedReport". At each `<a href>` i will call submit like `<a href="#" onclick=submit('reportName'); return=false;>reportName</a>`

And in the submit javascript, I will do

```
function submit (reportName){
    document.formName.hiddenField.value=reportName;
    document.formName.submit();
}
```